# Notification from startForeground inside service does not show sometimes

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have some users intermittently reporting that a notification for an incoming phone call isn't being shown. One time it is, another it isn't. One of them is on 8.1, and the other on 9. It mostly works for them, but sometimes it simply does not show.

When a push notification arrives for a VoIP call I start a new service within the FirebaseMessagingService.  While in there, i create a new notification and call startForeground with the appropriate details.

The entire call work flow in the service works as expected nearly all the time (it took them a week to reproduce it and send logs once). The notification shows, the phone rings, and everything is fine.

But sometimes (rarely) it rings which is triggered in the service after showing the notification, and no notification gets shown.

I confirmed this by adding this code and calling it all around the incoming call workflow and it logs outputs of being found as expected, except when they say it's not working, and then it never logs anything.

```
private void logNotificationStatus(String logDetail) {
        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                StatusBarNotification[] notificationList = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
                for (StatusBarNotification notification : notificationList) {
                    if (notification.getId() == INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION) {
                        Timber.tag(TAG).d("INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION %s", logDetail);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Timber.tag(TAG).e("Error checking notification status");
        }
    }
```

My app has the correct permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />`

I am calling startForeground with a non 0 id.

DND is off

My first instinct after confirming that sometimes it wasn't showing was that they had disabled notifications, or disabled the notification channel, but they claim that they have not done that (even accidentally) and sent a screenshot of notifications on, and all channels enabled.

This is where I'm creating the notification. The entire call process and all logging happens as expected, except when the problem happens, the call to `logNotificationStatus` logs nothing, but everything else works.

```
 public static final int INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION = 76;

 private void createIncomingNotification(CallWaitingNotificationType callWaitingNotificationType) {
        Timber.tag(TAG).d("Creating Incoming Notification");
        NotificationHelper.createChannels(VoipService.this);

        Intent incomingIntent = CallActivity.newInstanceIntent(getContext(), CallLoadType.INCOMING, false, false, voipPhone.getRecipientContactId());
        incomingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, incomingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent answerIntent = new Intent(this, VoipService.class);
        PendingIntent answerPendingIntent;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            answerIntent.setAction(callWaitingNotificationType.getAnswerAction().getAnswerAction());
        } else {
            answerIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.ANSWER_CALL_WITHOUT_PERMISSIONS);
        }

        answerPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, answerIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent hangUpIntent = new Intent(this, VoipService.class);
        hangUpIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.HANG_UP_CALL);
        PendingIntent hangUpPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, hangUpIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, callWaitingNotificationType.getChannelId())
                .setContentTitle(getVoipPhone().getRecipientText())
                .setTicker(getVoipPhone().getRecipientText())
                .setContentText("Incoming Call")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .setPriority(callWaitingNotificationType.getPriority())
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_call_end_white_24dp, "Hang Up", hangUpPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_call_white_24dp, "Answer", answerPendingIntent)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);

        Timber.tag(TAG).d("Notification Builder Created");

        startForeground(INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION, builder.build());
    }
```

I can't find anything else online describing this problem, it's always did you have permission, did you have a notification channel, and did you use a 0 ID, all of which I'm doing correctly.

I'm starting to wonder, if maybe sometimes startForeground is throwing an error and not logging it, because if you look in the `Service` class, it shows a caught but ignored exception

```
 public final void startForeground(int id, Notification notification) {
        try {
            mActivityManager.setServiceForeground(
                    new ComponentName(this, mClassName), mToken, id,
                    notification, 0);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        }
    }
```

I've tried putting bad data into all the builder fields, and in all cases it shows the notification in some way or another, and `logNotificationStatus` logs the notification.

I'm at a total loss of what to do next to try and figure out what is going on?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is the notification channel being created with IMPORTANCE_HIGH? check this:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance

Comment: Ya, they are high priority, but priority only changes how a notification is shown.  It is always created and displayed in one way or another though (such as below the fold forf silent notifications).  These notifications always show up as found in my code that looks for notifications by ID.  If you turn the notification channel OFF the notification doesn't show, but they claim they didn't do that.